# Conflict : 'space Bar' changes to 'tab' when something is edited

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, tortoisegit

I am getting this conflict every now and then, the spaces(....) are shown as a tab(->) when I am changing something in code. I am attaching an image, where I compared my file with the previous one. If anyone encountered with same error please let me know.

Conflict Image:
[image: Conflict Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change to an external comparer, one that can be configured or setup the code formatting in visual studio to adhere to the project formating guidelines whatever they are.

To configure the Visual Studio, just go `Tools --> Options --> Text editor --> All languages (or the one you are using) --> Tabs` and change the settings to whatever behaviour works for you.

Comment: Glad to help, check the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have the editor tool configured the use tabs instead of spaces.

How you can control this in VS is answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/51922994/3906760.

There is, however, another way how this could be controled from "the outside". There is [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) (you can spot this, if there is an `.editorconfig` file your repository), then on save the files will be converted automatically. This is also a way, to consistently push the coding rules to other developers.